# unknown JS error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using js function to changes class and text of li in my html document. Its working fine in every browser except IE8 and IE7. I dont what is the response. It is just a simple function . I am not getting any clue where to google it.

In group parameter I pass javascript object like:

```
var group = {
    0: {
        class: "classname1",
        text: "mytext"
    },
    2: {
        removeClass: "classname2",
        text: 'mytext2'
    },
    remove: [4, 5]
}
```

if (!Array.isArray) {
        Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
            return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
        };
    }

```
function xyz(group, parent) {
    $.each(group, function (key, val) {
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            var $lis = $(parent).find("li");
            for (var i = $lis.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (val.indexOf(i) > -1) $lis.eq(i).remove();
            }
        } else {
            $(parent).find('li').eq(key).removeClass(val.removeClass).addClass(val.class).text(val.text)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Array.isArray` is only supported in IE9 and above.

Put this in front of your code in order to support older versions of IE:

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
  };
}
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: any alternative for Array.isArray

Comment: @amit Make sure the polyfill occurs in the code before calling the `xyz` function otherwise, the polyfill will not have loaded when `Array.isArray` is called.

Comment: @amit please put your code on jsFiddle so we can look further into it.

Comment: @amit the problem is in `.addClass(val.class)`. `class` is a reserved property name for Internet Explorer - you cannot use it. Rename the property to something else, like `val.cssClass`.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft, Array.isArray() is not supported until IE9+.

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff848265(v=vs.94).aspx